# How to disable <span> tag conditionally in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a requirement where I need to conditionally disable a button and apply a tooltip based on certain conditions in an Angular application. Here's the code I currently have:

```
<span *ngIf="(hourEnabled && theTest && theTest2)" disabled="(comment.oS === true || comment.hFS) ? true : null" [matTooltip]="(comment.oS === true || comment.hFS) ? pendingToolTipText : null" matTooltipPosition="above"
      class="text-xs">Hi</span>
```

I expect that when the conditions are met, the button should be disabled and the tooltip should be displayed. When the conditions are not met, the button should be enabled and the tooltip should not be displayed.

However, the code does not give me the desired visual result. For now the conditions are matching but only the tooltip message is shown the button is still clickable.

Can anyone suggest the correct way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such things as a `disabled` span. The `disabled` attributes works only on forms.

The best way to achieve the result you would get is to apply a specific class on the component dynamically and toggle that class

So for example:

```
<span *ngIf="(hourEnabled && theTest && theTest2)" ng-class="{ disabled: comment.oS === true || comment.hFS }" [matTooltip]="(comment.oS === true || comment.hFS) ? pendingToolTipText : null" matTooltipPosition="above"
  class="text-xs">Hi</span>
```

and then you style your disable class as you wish. A simple example here:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: "none",
    cursor: "not-allowed",
}
```

Comment: [reference stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/yovbus?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts)